# Compare tool visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

[image]

This is how compare tool in visual studio 2012 is displayed ; is there any solution to make it show two files instead of one ?

Comment: Try "Ctrl + \, Ctrl + 2", which is "Side by Side" mode. There is an icon on the toolbar but it's a bit difficult to notice at times.

Comment: @Dismissile Please post that as an answer.